# Logic evaluation with && and || in a statement

Tags: java, logical-operators

I'm just debugging some code and found some expression:

```
if (mObject != null && a || b )
{
    mObject.someMethod();
}
```

which had a NullPointerException in the mObject.someMethod() line - so my question is:

how is the expression evaluated?

```
1. a && b || c == a && (b || c)
```

or

```
2. a && b || c == (a && b) || c
```

If 1. is the case i'd probably have to look at some multithreading issues.

This is probably a dumb question and i'm pretty sure it has been asked before, but i can't find the answer here. Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: if in second any one is true either a or b it will execute the  mObject.someMethod(); code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!=` has precedence over `&&` which has precedence over `||` ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html))

Therefore

```
if (mObject != null && a || b )
```

is equivalent to

```
if (((mObject != null) && a) || b )
```

To avoid the exception, use parentheses :

```
if (mObject != null && (a || b) )
```

Answer (score 7):

It is equivalent to the following condition:

```
if ((mObject != null && a) || b )
```

`&&` has a higher precedence that `||`.

If `mObject` is null, the condition may pass if `b` is true.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php), it's:

```
((( mObject != null ) && a ) || b )
```

so you should be looking into b, because:

```
(null != null) is false
false && a is always false
```

everything depends on b then.

Answer (score 0):

If parentheses are not provided then it will be always evaluated from left to right of the equals expression.